# Conditionally enable edit in lightning:datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-datatable

I'm trying to do a dynamic editable field, this is what I've got:

`Component`

```
<lightning:datatable columns="{!v.columns}"
            data="{! v.data }"
            keyField="{! v.keyField }"
            onsave="{! c.handleSaveEdition }"
            />
```

`data`

```
[
    {field1: 't1c1', field2: 't1c2', field3: 't1c3', field3Editable: true},
    {field1: 't2c1', field2: 't2c2', field3: 't3c3', field3Editable: true},
    {field1: 't2c1', field2: 't2c2', field3: 't3c3', field3Editable: false},
];
```

`column`

```
[
    {label: 'Col 1', fieldName: 'field1', type: 'text', sortable: false},
    {label: 'Col 2', fieldName: 'field2', type: 'text', sortable: false},
    {label: 'Col 3', fieldName: 'field3', type: 'text', sortable: false, editable: {fieldName: 'field3Editable'}},
];
```

but even with the last "field3Editable" from data seted as false the field appears as editable.

Answer (score 7):

Per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation), the `editable` attribute for `lightning:datatable` is applicable directly at the column level, and it does not mention anything at cell level, excerpt below:

> Specifies whether a column supports inline editing. The default is false.

With a quick test, I could confirm that you won't be able to disable a particular cell in a `lightning:datatable` with the syntax you have currently. With what you have currently `editable: {fieldName: 'field3Editable'}` is not the right syntax based on the documentation. The attribute itself should be set to `editable: true` or `editable: false`.

The syntax that you have currently seems to be always evaluated as `editable: true` by the platform, most likely it simply ignores any error and sets it to true. Even if you say have something as `editable: {nonExistentFieldName: 'nonExistentFieldValue'}` you will be still able to see that the cells are editable.

If you want to disable any particular cell, you may have to look at alternative solutions here as you may not be able to achieve it using `lightning:datatable`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to disable a particular cell in a datatable. 
Using CSS you can grey out the cell.

```
[
    {label: 'Col 1', fieldName: 'field1', type: 'text', sortable: false},
    {label: 'Col 2', fieldName: 'field2', type: 'text', sortable: false},
    {label: 'Col 3', fieldName: 'field3', type: 'text', sortable: false, editable: true , **cellAttributes: { class: { fieldName: 'disable' } }**},
];

[
    {field1: 't1c1', field2: 't1c2', field3: 't1c3', disable: ''},
    {field1: 't2c1', field2: 't2c2', field3: 't3c3', disable: ''},
    {field1: 't2c1', field2: 't2c2', field3: 't3c3', disable: 'greyOut'},
];
```

**CSS:**

```
.THIS .greyOut{    
   pointer-events: none; 
   background: #CCC; 
   color: #333; 
   border: 1px solid #666 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally edit by doing the following in the LWC datatable:

In your table columns define editable as such

```
COLUMN = [
{label: 'Col 3', fieldName: 'field3', type: 'text', sortable: false, editable: {fieldName: 'controlEditField'}]
```

In your data include the controlling field like

```
data = {
   field3: 'Some Value',
   controlEditField: false
}
```

You can manipulate the controlling field via JS or in your Apex logic.

Comment: That's exactly what OP states they have tried which did not work.  I have likewise tried this without success.  If you have made this work please include a full working example in your answer.